# How to remove duplicated columns and to retain only the longest one?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe with several columns, and some columns show overlapping values each others.
I'll give an example of two overlapping columns of this dataframe:

```
V1976   V2066
206603  211261
216048  211948
212817  217609
211949  211949
210174  210174
217693 4400786
216383  208238
217609  212817
4400786  204737
208238  210317
210317  218167
216049      NA
211948      NA
204737      NA
218167      NA
```

I would like to write a function in which retaining the longest column in between columns with overlapping values.
In the example, I would like to retain the first column V1976 in the dataframe.
How can I do it in R?
Many thanks!

Comment: By "longest" do you mean most non NA values?

Comment: How do you define "overlapping values"?

Comment: yep, the longest without NA values

Comment: overlapping means that values of the second column are also within the first column

Comment: `setdiff(quux[[2]], quux[[1]])` shows that `211261` is in the second column but not the first, and `c(206603L, 216048L, 217693L, 216383L, 216049L)` are in the first but not the second. In this case, your expected output is the original data, unmodified?

Comment: To clarify your question: let `w <- c(1, 2, NA, NA, NA)` and `x <- c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA)` and `y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA)` and `z <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1)`.  You want some function `fn()` where `fn(w, x, y, z)` will return `z`?  Because `z` is the "longest" of the two columns (`y` and `z`) that are [supersets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#Definition) of the rest (`w` and `x`)?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you mean for this

```
> l <- sapply(df, \(x) length(unique(na.omit(x))))

> df[l == max(l)]
     V1976
1   206603
2   216048
3   212817
4   211949
5   210174
6   217693
7   216383
8   217609
9  4400786
10  208238
11  210317
12  216049
13  211948
14  204737
15  218167
```